# bsearch() returns (nil), causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, bsearch

The bserach() function should return NULL but instead, I get (nil) when it is unable to find the key in the given array.
What's going wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int cmpfunc(const void * a, const void * b)
{
   return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}    
int values[] = { 5, 20, 29, 32, 63 };    
int main ()
{
   int *item;
   int key = 10;

   /* using bsearch() to find value 32 in the array */
   item = (int*) bsearch (&key, values, 5, sizeof (int), cmpfunc);
   if( item != NULL ) 
   {
      printf("Found item = %d\n", *item);
   }
   else 
   {
      printf("Item = %d could not be found\n", *item);
   }       
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: There's no `nil` in C. `NULL` is effectively the same thing, though.

Comment: In C you should not cast `void *`. Doing so can actually hide problems with you forgetting to declare the function you're calling (or forgetting to include the correct header file). In C all pointers are implicitly convertable to `void*` and the other way around. Then only time you need to explicitly cast a `void*` is when dereferencing such a pointer.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, s/all pointers/all object pointers/g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, in `else` part

```
if( item != NULL ) 
   {
      printf("Found item = %d\n", *item);
   }
   else 
   {
      printf("Item = %d could not be found\n", *item);
   }
```

even if `item` is `NULL`, youre dereferencing it [`*item`]. Please refrain from doing so.

To fix the issue keeping the informative output message intact, maybe you can use something

```
printf(" Any item with related key value %d could not be found\n", key);
```

when `item` is `NULL`.

Comment: `printf("Item = %d could not be found\n", key);` would be the safe fix.

Comment: @PaulRoub Indeed. Maybe `printf(" Any item with related key value %d could not be found\n", key);` will also do. :-)